# How to upload a file along with other data? Trouble understanding multipart form

Tags: javascript, rest, http, file-upload

I am trying to figure out how to make a rest `POST /image` to create a new image.  I want to send the file data and also a name and description from the user.

How does the request work in this case?  Also, can I use json for this?

Thanks

Comment: If you're sending multipart form, then JSON kind of doesn't make sense - they're both a way of structuring information in message body. Unless you make JSON one part of the multipart, but there's not too much reason I can think of to do that. [Here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages) a quick description of MIME multipart.

Comment: If you are using [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), just [`append(name, text)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) what ever extra data fields you want to add. The `append()` method isn't only for files. Each `append()` call adds a separate part. That's why its called Multipart; we can add multiple parts of different types as one entity body.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to append the file/data about that file in the FormData object, like this :

```
const file_data = new FormData();
const imgFile = this.uploadInput.files[0]; /*whatever your file is, from the input tag*/

file_data.append('imgFile', imgFile);    /*the image file*/
file_data.append('name', "name of file")    
file_data.append('description', "description of file");
```

And on the server side nodeJS, you could extract the info from request like :

```
var image = req.files.imgFile;
var name = req.body.name;
var description = req.body.description;
/*save'em to database or something*/
```

you see that the files in FormData will be extracted from req.files and not req.body !

Edit: You might wanna set the '**Content-Type**' header on your request as '**multipart/form-data**'